# udev видит не тот серийный номер usb устройства

Tags: linux, usb, udev

На некоторых компах, разных версий udev и ядра переодически возникает и пропадает сама по себе такая проблема.

Вчера принтер имел такой адрес:

```
hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_P1102?serial=000000000Q895JERPR1a
```

Сегодня у него:

```
hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_P1102?serial=000000000Q895JERSI1c
```

Вот он меняется туда-обратно в течении недель двух, а потом полгода стабильно. На других устройствах (не принтерах) такое тоже случалось.
Страдают 4 компа этим(разные года, производства, ничего общего), еще несколько очень редко, но были замечены. При смене компа глюк пропадает.

Comment: как это «не тот»? какой устройство сообщает, **именно такой** и «видит».

Comment: как устройство может сообщать разные серийники?

Comment: адресуйте вопрос устройству. не самому устройству, конечно, а производителю микросхемы (или её «прошивки») usb-контроллера, впаянной в устройство изготовителем.

Comment: если бы был глюк контроллера, то я бы получал серийники с мусором или всегда разные. меняются 2 серийника по очереди одни и те же.

Comment: не стоит называть глюком то, что можно назвать фичей.

Comment: я раньше думал на глюк прошивки хп, но приметил на других усб железках. может драйвер дергает из разных регистров и выдает тот что пришел первый?

Comment: нет, это то, что сообщает контроллер. а он может сообщать разное: http://muhdzamri.blogspot.com/2012/12/problem-setting-up-hp-laserjet-p1102-on.html (найдено поиском сначала «hp 1102 pr1a», затем «hp 1102 si1c»)

Comment: Похожий случай, но там проблем с модесвич. У меня он печатает на обоих серийниках

Comment: там проблема с контроллером. который представляется то одним usb-устройством, то другим. ровно так же, как и у вас. судя по результатам, выдаваемых яндексом, `*pr1a` — это usb-интерфейс принтера, а `*si1c` — дисковода. поройтесь в настройках/интернетах — может быть это отключаемо (как в некоторых контроллерах usb-модемов). но для начала соберите информацию dmesg-ом.

Comment: странно что в дмесге нет про сидиром. сначала попробую обновить, а потом  удалить модесвич) может не будет переключать туда-сюда

Comment: @eri, `usb-mode-switch` к серийному номеру не имеет никакого отношения! Как раз в статье пишут как сказать контроллеру на принтере, чтобы он этого не делал.

Answer (score 1):

> ERPR1a
>   устройство в режиме принтера
>
> ERSI1c
>   устройство в режиме cd-rom (модель HP P1102 оснащена функцией SmartInstall)

Comment: да, знаю. но эндпоинта сидирова на усб шине нет. в обоих случаях эндпоинты печати. как их зафисировать или програмно переключить?

Comment: Для отключения виртуального CD-ROM на принтере воспользуемся фирменной утилитой — HP Smart Install Utility Скачиваем с официального сайта или в корне установочного диска с драйверами от принтера зайти в папку «UTIL» и в соответствии с разрядностью вашей ОС запустить файл «SIUtility.exe» или  «SIUtility64.exe» потом в открывшемся окне нажать кнопочку «Printer», выбрать нужный принтер и нажать кнопочку «Next», в появившемся окне нажать кнопочку «Disable HP Smart Install…»

http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/COL53550/lj-129224-1/LJP1100_P1560_P1600_SI_Utility.exe

Comment: Проблема в том что он на линуксе и за 100км от меня)

Comment: мы тоже думали как отключить эту функцию на пачке принтеров разбросанных по регионам.

ставим на windows клиент,
на линукс сервер - 
http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network-download.html#tab_usbnet-win-current

делаем проброс портов

видим принтер в windows, ну а далее утилитой которая в моём предыдущем комментарии.

для удалённого доступа использовали ssh и https://www.nomachine.com/ru